# Como contar acessos únicos semanais em MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho essa consulta em MySQL para verificar os acessos únicos a um sistema meu:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_usuario) AS total, dia FROM acesso
WHERE (dia BETWEEN '2018-01-21' AND '2019-01-21')
GROUP BY dia
ORDER BY dia ASC
```

E ao meu ver ele está listando certo os acessos únicos ao sistema.

**Minha dúvida**: o cliente pediu para checar os acessos únicos semanais, ou seja, se o usuário acessar ao menos 1 única vez durante o período de 1 semana, já contaria o acesso dele, como fazer? Tentei assim, mas o total acaba dando menor que o acesso único diário:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_usuario) AS total, dia FROM acesso
WHERE (dia BETWEEN '2018-01-21' AND '2019-01-21')
GROUP BY WEEK(dia)
ORDER BY dia ASC
```

Comment: Qual a versão do `MySQL`?

Comment: Versão do cliente de base de dados: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 76b08b24596e12d4553bd41fc93cccd5bac2fe7a $

Answer (score 0):

Se você fizer esta query, vai criar uma tabela analítica com os distintos numa determinada semana, filtrando por intervalo de datas

```
SELECT id_usuario, week(dia) as semana FROM acesso
WHERE dia  BETWEEN '2019-01-01' and '2019-04-16'
group by id_usuario, week(dia)
```

Com base nestes resultados, você pode contar os distintos neste intervalo de tempo

```
SELECT count(distinct id_usuario) as total from (SELECT id_usuario, week(dia) as semana FROM acesso
WHERE dia  BETWEEN '2019-01-01' and '2019-04-16'
group by id_usuario, week(dia)) T
```

Comment: Aqui da esse erro: <b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\PCA_brasilprev_blog\dashboard.php</b> on line <b>56</b> LINHA 56 é onde está a consulta ao MySQL

Comment: @Bins, vc não precisa adicionar várias respostas. Se uma das respostas não funcionou, basta editá-la, corrigindo os problemas e acrescentado informações conforme necessário. Editar as postagens é uma prática comum e até mesmo incentivada no site: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Answer (score -1):

Se você deseja saber apenas o total de acessos nos últimos 7 dias, pode fazer desta forma:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_usuario) AS total FROM acesso
WHERE dia  >= (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: Não... preciso saber em qualquer data. Exemplo: de 2017 até 2019.... ai listo as semanas... e ao lado quantos acessos únicos